# Ubuntu VM failed to update (clearsigned files isn't valid got NOSPLIT)

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, virtual-machine, virtualbox

My host machine is behind a company proxy and running windows 7. I have a ubuntu 16.04 VM (NAT) where I am trying to do `apt-get update`.

The update throws an error

```
Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease Clearsigned file isnt valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does network require authentication?)
```

On my host machine I have http_proxy set as `http://company.net:port`. How do I resolve this error on the VM?

Answer (score 1):

Export the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables using the form that includes authentication data if required.  Then make sure you pass the `-E` argument to `sudo` if you use it to run `apt-get` e.g.

`sudo -E apt-get update`.

This will ensure that your environment variables are preserved by `sudo` when it executes your command.

Answer (score 0):

you can try /etc/apt/apt.conf as below;

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@company.net:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@company.net:port/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@company.net:port/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://username:password@company.net:port/";
```

Answer (score 0):

For me works if I change network adapter from Bridge with replication of state to NAT, this changes IP address

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for the answer - changing all the repository links from http to https worked for me 
[reference link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537051/apt-get-update-failing)